# Android achartengine: Cannot draw multiple lines in a graph

Tags: java, android, android-layout, graph, achartengine

I am drawing lines on a graph based on the equations that a user inputs. If a user inputs multiple lines, the lines cannot be drawn.

Here is my code:

```
public void drawGraph(View v) {
    EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String equation = target.getText().toString();

    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    if (!equation.isEmpty()) {
        String[] sides = equation.split("=");
        List<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();
        String tempString = "";

        if (sides.length > 1) {
            String rightSide = sides[1];
            char[] rightSideCharacters = rightSide.toCharArray();

            for (char c : rightSideCharacters) {
                if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                    tempString = String.valueOf(c);
                    variables.add(String.valueOf(c));
                }
            }

            boolean duplicates = duplicates(variables);


                if (duplicates == false) {
                    lines++;

                    seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                    seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                    seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(143, 2, 2));
                    seriesRenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
                    seriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                    seriesRenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);

                    seriesRenderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                    seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                    seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 90, 238));
                    seriesRenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
                    seriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                    seriesRenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);

                    if (lines == 1) {
                        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
                    }
                    if (lines == 2) {
                        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
                        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer2);
                    }

                    // We want to avoid black border
                    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00)); // transparent margins
                    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
                    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(range);
                    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-range);
                    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(range);
                    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(-range);
                    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true); // we show the grid

                    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

                    String originalRight = rightSide;
                    //System.out.println(range);

                    for (double i = -range; i < range; i++) {
                        rightSide = rightSide.replaceAll(tempString, "(" + String.valueOf(i) + ")");
                        math.setVariable(tempString, i);
                        if (lines == 1) {
                            graph.add(i, math.evaluate(rightSide.substring(1)));
                        }
                        if (lines == 2) {
                            System.out.println(i + "," + math.evaluate(rightSide.substring(1)));
                            graph2.add(i, math.evaluate(rightSide.substring(1)));
                        }
                        rightSide = originalRight;
                    }

                    if (lines == 1) {
                        dataset.addSeries(graph);
                    }
                    if (lines == 2) {
                        dataset.addSeries(graph);
                        dataset.addSeries(graph2);
                    }

                    chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer);
                    //chartView.repaint();
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartlayout);
                    layout.addView(chartView);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                seriesRenderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
                seriesRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 90, 238));
                seriesRenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
                seriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                seriesRenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);
```

should have seriesRenderer2.setLineWidth(2);